# Android ImageView image not showing

Tags: android, image, vector, imageview

I currently am working with an imageview to display a vector drawable. Which it will not display, but it does display the icon in androidstudio on the left side. The code can be seen below:

**EDIT**
I set the weight to 0 to display it at the end of the linearlayout. It does not bug the width or height out.
***The layout is not the issue, the displaying is***

As you can see, the vector is valid on the left side
[image]

Code of popup:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/report_template_edit_draft_popup"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@color/pspdf__color_white"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="@string/report_template_popup_window_title"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/report_template_popup_close_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="0"
                android:minHeight="30dp"
                android:minWidth="30dp"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_close" />


    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

The problem is that it does not show up in the design not in the application.

[image]

And yes , I am using this in my build.gradle

```
vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary true
```

ic_close.xml

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:width="24dp"
        android:height="24dp"
        android:viewportHeight="24.0"
        android:viewportWidth="24.0">
    <path
        android:fillColor="#ffffff"
        android:pathData="M19,6.41L17.59,5 12,10.59 6.41,5 5,6.41 10.59,12 5,17.59 6.41,19 12,13.41 17.59,19 19,17.59 13.41,12z"/>
</vector>
```

Comment: Why are You using the `layout-weight=0`

Comment: May be issue with your layout? share your whole xml layout as text

Comment: To fit the image at the end of the linearlayout @RavindraKushwaha

Comment: check the answer by @mahdi. try using src instead of using srcCompat with ImageView

Comment: @faiizii Any reason to use the `src` instead of the `srcCompact` ?

Comment: using src is also not working, this method works in another part of my code

Comment: try different image in `src` this may not shown because of having background and image have same color

Comment: you just need to remove layout_weight="0". and you're done

Comment: because there is scaling issue with the Image bitmap. and src will do it auto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look on the below layout, i have used the `android:weightSum` for the properly assign the weight to the view.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/report_template_edit_draft_popup"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="1">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.1"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:text=" i am ravibndra kushwaha have alook on the solution"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/report_template_popup_close_button"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="0.9"
                android:minHeight="30dp"
                android:minWidth="30dp"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_close" />


        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, no need to add android:layout_weight="0", you can use it like..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/report_template_edit_draft_popup"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="some text"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/report_template_popup_close_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:minHeight="30dp"
                android:minWidth="30dp"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_dummy" />


        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>`
</LinearLayout>
```

Second, try to use different vector icon or change layout background color or vector icon color, may be the issue with the white over white color.

Answer (score 0):

`app:srcCompat` must be used with `AppCompatImageView`. If you want to use ImageView, you have to use `android:src`

change it in this way:

```
<ImageView 
    <!-- your other attributes -->
    android:src="@drawable/ic_close"/>
```

or in this way :

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
                        <!-- your other attributes -->
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_close"

                />
```

**EDIT:**

also remove `android:layout_weight="0"` form `ImageView`
and replace `android:layout_width="match_parent"` with `android:layout_width="0dp"` from TextView

EDIT2:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
                        android:layout_width="30dp"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_close"
                        android:adjustViewBounds="true"

                />
```

> To create a linear layout in which each child uses the same amount of
>   space on the screen, set the android:layout_height of each view to
>   "0dp" (for a vertical layout) or the android:layout_width of each view
>   to "0dp" (for a horizontal layout). Then set the android:layout_weight
>   of each view to "1".

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear

Comment: which API level do you use for your app?

Comment: I am using level 27

Comment: replace android:layout_width="match_parent" with android:layout_width="0dp" in TextView

Comment: As I said, it is not a layout issue. It fits perfectly

Comment: I use the second edit over image view properties, i works for me, replace minHeight and minWidth With other mentioned properties

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
android:id="@+id/reprt_template_popup_close_button"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center"
androi:minHeight="30dp"
androi:minWidth="30dp"
app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_close"
/>
```

Weight is not needed for the one above

To make it like you showed in the image

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="@string/report_template_popup_window_title"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/report_template_popup_close_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:minHeight="30dp"
            android:minWidth="30dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_close" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: We should use layout_weight along with either layout_height="odp" or layout_weight="0dp". And a weight of 0 means it should not take up any space

Comment: As I mentioned, it is not a layout issue. It fits perfectly